# Detecting different paths on a map from a top view

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, robotics

Map for the robot: [image: map]

Hi, I am very new to computer vision. I have a layout of map consisting 3 routes. I want to be able to identify the map and the 3 routes separately. When I have a gap between the tape as seen in the image I am able to identify the different routes with the help of Hough line transform function. However if I remove the gap and all the routes are joined together it is identified as one route. Also the program gets distracted by random lines of objects outside the route which I do not want. How can I fix this or what should I look into to.

I have attempted sobel edge detection and canny. I was thinking about implementing some sort of feature to identify it by orientation or just Identify the junctions. Even when I use those libraries it identifies the lines unclearly.

Comment: wrong approach. forget everything you've learned in a blog post or youtube video. that means: forget canny, hough, and template matching. those are newbie traps. you **need** a proper book or course on computer vision. can't wing it. -- in what possible ways will this "map" (sticky tape on the floor) be viewed?

Comment: My main goal of this project is to identify all the routes (which are currently constructed from black tape which I might need to adjust as it is very reflective and doesnt work well with opencv) from the top view. detect any obstacles that may block a route and calculate the fastest route. This information will send to the robot that has been constructed.

Comment: segmentation. threshold the grayscale image. -- perhaps take a proper top-down picture and fix the illumination so this thing is lit uniformly without reflections. light from the side to make reflections miss the camera.